# Does anyone have the old grammar book "A Spanish Grammar" by Coester? check the index please for hacer

Tags: gramática

Me encantan los libros antiguos.

[En Inglés]
If you have this old grammar book, can you please check the index for the word "hacer", which it refers to page 104 for the infinitive.  However, I see no mention of *hacer* on that page.  Am I missing something?

| [image] *[Original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtrC9.jpg)* | [image] *[Original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPzo3.png)* | [image] *[Original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJK2M.png)* | [image] *[Original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtrC9.jpg)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: I can't see what you say [_A Spanish Grammar_](https://archive.org/details/cu31924012583328/page/n9/mode/2up)

Comment: Ok, I added a snapshot of the page being referenced.  Sorry, I was hoping someone had this book.  I only included the 2nd snapshot to show the date of the book.  So, If you or anyone can zoom in on that 3rd photo, and see if you can spot ANY mention of hacer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not post images like this as they are not searchable and people who can't see well, cannot see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **section index**:

[image]

Consequently, it does not refer to page 104 but to section 104 (pages 84-85), point *c*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was missing something.